# In my application in java database connection code is not working

Tags: java, database, sqlite, desktop-application

In this code class.forname it show error that class not found
so help me with this code because my is a local database application
I am using sqlite database.

```
package appview;

import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
  import java.sql.ResultSet;  
 import java.sql.Statement;


 public class Databaseconnection {

Connection connection = null; 

  public static Connection connection2() 
  {  



     try 
     {  
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
       Connection connection =           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Jainam\\Java Application\\JPH\\src\\database\\jph_db.sqlite");  

         return connection;
     } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {  
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }




  }  


 }
```

Comment: *What* class is not found?

Comment: post ur logcat file ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the url this way: `jdbc:sqlite:/DRIVE:/dirA/dirB/dbfile`

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Users/Jainam/Java Application/JPH/src/database/jph_db.sqlite");
```

See [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite/Connecting) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` means Java is not able to find the `org.sqlite.JDBC` class. You need to Download `sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.1.jar` and put it in your class-path before running it.

Comment: How to put that file in class path

Comment: either use `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<sqlite jdbc jar with path>` (on windows), `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;<sqlite jdbc jar full path>` (on unix) or you can do it with -cp option like `java -cp <sqlite jdbc jar with path> <main class>`

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm) check database connectivity.

class not found ? then go for DDMS->FILE EXP-> SDCARD -> INSERT UR SQLITE.DB file.It will run proper.